changing uuid of /run/media/root/ partition
I have a usb disk and after formatting it shows up as /run/media/root/abc213 where abc123 is some much longer complex string that no normal person would be able to remember... typical of what you would see for UUID's in /etc/fstab.
Is there a way to change this uuid string on my usb disk after I have that partition formatted as XFS?   Such that I could make its UUID one single character, and if so how?

UUID can be changed but only to another UUID, so the same 32 digits long string. But udisks (system daemon that is doing the mounting) will use filesystem label if it has one so simply run
xfs_admin -L <label> <device>

to set any label you want for your device (even just one letter if you want) and next time it will be mounted to /run/media/<user>/<label>.
